# How to use TF 2.0 tf.recompute_grad?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I wanted to use memory saving gradients (openai/gradient-checkpointing) to reduce GPU memory cost of my neural network, but I found that it's impossible in TF 2.0, but also I have found that I can use tf.recompute_grad for this purpose. I didn't found any examples or tutorials on Google, so I ask here. Also, is it possible to use this with tf.keras?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. Did you end up figuring out a method?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well. Did you end up figuring out a method?